# Switch statement case not being called when using UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `TableViewController` with a `UITableView`, the view controller class has a variable called `isFolder`.

Throughout the `ViewController` I use a switch statement to determine which variable I should be using either `selectedFolder1` or `selectedObjects`. Each variable is a NSManagedObject subclass and has an `arrayOfItems` method which returns an array.

When preparing for segue `isFolder` has a value depending on the data being passed.

All this works fine. The problem is when the data is passed and I use a switch statement to populate the table. When the switch statement case is `true` for `isFolder` it is not being called for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` table function but is for `numberOfRowsInSection`. However when I reload the view after dismissing a modal view the data appears.

For e.g.

This function works fine and the switch statement case true is called.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch isFolder {
    case true: print("no. of cells for folder"); return self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems.count
    case false: print("no. of cells for object"); return self.selectedObject.arrayOfItems.count
    }
}
```

However the following function to populate the tableview cells the switch statement case for true is not called.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let color = colorWheel()
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.backgroundColor = color.white

    switch isFolder {
    case true:
        print("Using selected Folder")
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedFolder.arrayOfItems[indexPath.row].title

    case false:
        print("Using selected Object")
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedObject.arrayOfItems[indexPath.row].title

    }
    return cell
}
```

When the case is false everything works fine and the data is displayed first time. As mentioned the table displays the data if the switch statement is true but only when I dismiss a modal view and post a notification to call `self.table.reloadData()`. I do call the table method `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad` but that doesn't do anything.

Does anybody have any suggestions ?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection)` what is the value of `self.selectedFolder.arrayOfItems.count` for the true case? If it is zero, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't be called

Comment: Oh right, it is 0. I thought because the print was called in `numberOfRows` the same number of times as the array count it should be fine. What I have now done when calling `prepareForSegue` I regenerate the array.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your data objects are populated before calling reloadData() on your UITableView object. Otherwise, if `numberOfRowsInSections` returns 0, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not be called